# store some values into variables and show them afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to store some values into variables and show them afterwards with a alertbox.

```
$('[name=scope]').each(function() {
  var scope = this.value;
});
$('[name=client_id]').each(function() {
  var client_id = this.value;
});
alert(scope);
```

But I dont get a alertbox. What can i do to fix this?

Comment: Set `var scope` outside  `$('[name=scope]').each(function() {` and use `scope = this.value;` in `.each`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `scope` of variables are **local**

Declare them as **global** so that you can access afterwards

Example

```
var scope;
var client_id;
$('[name=scope]').each(function() {
  scope = this.value;
});
$('[name=client_id]').each(function() {
  client_id = this.value;
});
alert(scope);
```

Comment: no :) when u need to access something afterwards, global is not bad :)

Comment: if this answer helped you, dont forget to check this as correct answer :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

Because `scope` is out of scope. Javascript is function scope language. Variables declare inside in a function is only accessible in that function or  child ones(closures). You can declare a global variable(don't suggest it general but for your example)

```js
var scope;
$('[name=scope]').each(function() {
  scope = this.value;
});

console.log(scope);//logs test
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="scope" value="test" />
```

Another example:

```js
var c = 3;

function test() {
  var a = 1;

  function b() {
    console.log(a);
  }
  b(); //prints 1
  c = 4;
}

test();
console.log(c);//prints 4
console.log(a); //ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

**References**

[variable statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)